# SQL - Filter results for 1 column based on date in another column

Tags: sql, teradata

I had a tough time coming up with an appropriate title.  Here's the problem.  I'm trying to determine new users, month over month, by when they went into the tool and created a plan.

Here's what I have so far

```
select 
distinct userID, 
MIN(planID), 
MIN(PlanCreated)
from dataBaseName.tableName 
Group by userID
```

This provides me with the ground level information I need. I get the user and the first plan they created and when.

However I need to further refine this. Because some users go into the tool and only create the plan leaving it in a 'Draft' status and never return.  I need to filter out Draft plans that are older than 3 months.

There is a 'PlanStatus' column which filtering based on 'Draft' status is simple enough

```
where PlanStatus 
is not in 'Draft'
```

but again, I only want to remove those plans older than 3 months from the results.

ex. date format - 2017-01-01 00:00:00

I'm also not sure if this filter should be done first so the ID is not completely removed if they later created a plan and moved it out of Draft status.

Sample data:

```
planID | userID |    PlanCreated         |    PlanStatus |    OtherColumns

  1111 |      2 |    2016-01-17 00:00:00 |    Completed  |    null

  1112 |      1 |    2016-06-31 00:00:00 |    Draft      |    null

  1113 |      2 |    2017-01-24 00:00:00 |    Completed  |    null

  1114 |      3 |    2017-02-04 00:00:00 |    Draft      |    null

  1115 |      1 |    2017-03-12 00:00:00 |    Draft      |    null
```

Expected results:

```
planID | userID |    PlanCreated         |    PlanStatus |    OtherColumns

  1111 |      2 |    2016-01-17 00:00:00 |    Completed  |    null

  1114 |      3 |    2017-02-04 00:00:00 |    Draft      |    null

  1115 |      1 |    2017-03-12 00:00:00 |    Draft      |    null
```

Please help

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also sample data and desired results would  help.

Comment: Sample data added as well as desired results and database tagged

Comment: Caution, if the PlanId is not increasing sequentially you might get a wrong result when using `MIN(planID), 
MIN(PlanCreated)`. Do yo really want to return all columns or just those three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, where did you learn to use `select distinct` with aggregation functions.  The correct syntax is:

```
select userID, min(planID), min(PlanCreated)
from dataBaseName.tableName 
Group by userID;
```

There is not need for the `distinct`.  Then you want a `where`.  Here is one way:

```
select userID, min(planID), min(PlanCreated)
from dataBaseName.tableName 
where not (status = 'draft' and plandate < '2017-01-01')
Group by userID;
```

Note that the date functions and constants can vary by database.

Comment: The use of distinct was recommended by a co-worker.  I've been learning as I go for the past two weeks and hit a wall today.  This seems to do exactly what I need it to.  Next is to figure out how to use todays date - 3 months rather than hardcode the date.

Comment: @Zardoz . . . `.ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -3)`

Comment: @Zardoz . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT userID, MIN(planID) , MIN(PlanCreated) FROM dataBaseName.tableName 
WHERE  NOT (status = 'draft' AND DATEDIFF(DAY,   plancreated, getDate()) > 90)
GROUP BY userID
```

Comment: Unfortunately after putting in `where not (PlanStatus = 'Draft' and DATEDIFF(DAY, PlanCreated, getDate())>90)` I get the following error `Syntax error: expected something between '(' and the 'DAY' keyword.`

Comment: I don't know what you are using for your data, but what I think  is that 'DateDiff' is not supported.